# Swift - UITableViewCell class contentView programmatically constraints doesn't have width

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, constraints

```
class Cell:UITableViewCell {
   var myImage:UIImageView = UIImageView()
   override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        myImage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        time.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.addSubview(userImage)
        contentView.addSubview(time)
        let viewsDict = ["contentView":contentView,"myImage":myImage,"time":time]
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[contentView(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-30-[myImage(50)]-[time]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
        contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-25-[myImage(50)]-25-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
   }
}
```

I want time to be attached on the right side of the subview which is contentView, but it's next to the myImage:
[image: portrait mode]
even in landscape mode the contentView doesn't reach all screen:
[image: landscape mode]

I've tried with `contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[contentView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))`, but I received an error:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e5d7c0 H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x79e59f70]   (Names: '|':myApp.Cell:0x79e58f00'cell' )>
        When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
    2015-01-13 20:05:11.546 myApp[6117:775684] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
        Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e5d7c0 H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x79e59f70]   (Names: '|':myApp.Cell:0x79e58f00'cell' )>
        Container hierarchy: 
    <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x79e59f70; frame = (0 0; 320 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79e5a8a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e5a140>>
       | <UILabel: 0x79e59520; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x79e595e0>>
       | <UIImageView: 0x79e59750; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e597d0>>
        View not found in container hierarchy: <myApp.Cell: 0x79e58f00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x79e59b50>>
        That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
    2015-01-13 20:05:11.857 myApp[6117:775684] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e5d7c0 H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x79e59f70]   (Names: '|':myApp.Cell:0x79e58f00'cell' )> view:<UITableViewCellContentView: 0x79e59f70; frame = (0 0; 320 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x79e5a8a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x79e5a140>>'
```

UPDATE: I fix the width of the row when I add constraints to the tableView, but the label `time` still is not on the right side of the contentView. Any suggestions? It looks like contentView is not long like tableView width. I don't know...

Comment: You just need to change the text alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the contentView constraint on the superview:

```
contentView.superview.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[contentView(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

You might also need to call this for the cell to render correctly:

```
self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Comment: `self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` put it into Cell class breaks cells which have information. `contentView.superview?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[contentView(500)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))` this line doesn't do anything to the cell

Comment: When you added the contentView constraint to the superview, did you also remove the line adding it to the contentView? Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: yes I do, but the .superview doen't do anything it has to be contentView.addConstraints.... maybe this is bug I don't know..

Comment: `contentView.superview?.addSubview(timeLabel)`
`contentView.superview?.addConstraints(...)`
is the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the label text alignment to right, then the label will be aligned to the right side of the contentView. Something like this.

```
time.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the following setup for your constraints (replacing your code starting from the `viewDict` line):

```
let viewsDict = ["contentView":contentView,"myImage":myImage,"time":time]

self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[contentView(100)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[-10-contentView-10-]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-30-[myImage(50)]-(>=10)-[time]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-25-[myImage(50)]-25-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```